# scope on Date.current only updates when Rails restarts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

I have a Rails 3 app hosted on Heroku, running against a Postgres database. I have a controller action which is supposed to generate an RSS feed, but I'm finding that it never updates until the application restarts (either because I do a new release to Heroku, or because the site is inactive for a while so the dyno spins down and back up again). It is returning 'stale' data that excludes new items.

The scope is defined like so, based on a comparison between a row on my model called `date` and `Date.current`:

```
class Petition < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :current, where(["petitions.date <= ?", Date.current]).order("petitions.date DESC")
  scope :published, { :conditions => { :published => true } }
end
```

The controller action is like this:

```
class PetitionsController < ActionController::Base

  before_filter :find_diary

  def rss
    current_petitions.each do |petition|
      puts petition.date
    end                
  end

  protected

  def find_diary
    @diary = Diary.find(params[:id])
  end    

  def current_petitions
    @diary.petitions.published.current.limit(25)
  end
end
```

As you can see, it is supposed to return all petitions with a `date` that is today or earlier. It works fine on the Heroku console: `Diary.find(15).petitions.published.current.limit(25).first` always gives me one for today. I can see from the logs that it is calling that `current_petitions` function each time the feed is requested. But if I leave the site running for 24 hours then it still only shows me petitions up until yesterday. If I do a release to add any debug code, suddenly it will start working again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you set up a scope with a time in it you need to use a lambda expression to ensure that the time call is evaluated each time the scope is used. There are more details in the [rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.13/active_record_querying.html#working-with-times) but your scope needs to look more like:

```
scope :current, lambda { where(["petitions.date <= ?", Date.current]) }
```

Comment: Easy when you know how!